# Show current file name during git --patch

Tags: git, patch

When I `git add --patch` with large diffs and consequently several hunks, I often end up scrolling up to the first hunk to recover the name of the file I am actually patching.

Is there a way to print this name out from the command line? Or to update some config to enforce git to re-print it for each hunk ? Or any other solution ?

The standard commands do not seem to easily allow this:

```
y - stage this hunk
n - do not stage this hunk
q - quit; do not stage this hunk or any of the remaining ones
a - stage this hunk and all later hunks in the file
d - do not stage this hunk or any of the later hunks in the file
g - select a hunk to go to
/ - search for a hunk matching the given regex
j - leave this hunk undecided, see next undecided hunk
J - leave this hunk undecided, see next hunk
K - leave this hunk undecided, see previous hunk
e - manually edit the current hunk
? - print help
```

Comment: `git add --patch <filename>` This way you always know the filename.

Comment: The program that implements `git add -p` knows. It is or was a Perl program but all these things are being rewritten into C. You might look into the ongoing work here and supply a patch to the old and/or new code to add a new command to have this program tell you which file the patch hunk is for...